# What is the difference between the "Checkboxes (A)" and "Checkboxes (B)" dialogs in a Visual Studio setup project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, installation, setup-project

In a Visual Studio Setup & Deployment Project, I can design the user interface for the installer.  I have a welcome screen, a license acceptance dialog, and then an installation location dialog.  All good.

I want to include one more dialog, to confirm changing of file associations.  I think the way to do this is with a dialog that has a Checkbox.

I can right click the UI node, and select "Add Dialog" and I get this choice:

[image: checkboxes]

What is the difference between any of these checkboxes dialogs?

I tried to RTFM but couldn't find the doc on these options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

D'oh!  [I answered my own question](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b5sy4ht.aspx).

[image]

Comment: It's allowed - you never know someone else might be helped.