# In a Visual Studio Setup Project, How do I make update of the Registry conditional on a Checkbox dialog?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, registry, installation, setup-project

Currently I use Registry Settings within the Setup Project to set the file associations and the icon for the associated files for my application.

[image: Registry settings]

In the generic VS Setup project, the update to the registry is done always.  How can I make the update to the registry conditional on the state of [a checkbox dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b5sy4ht.aspx)?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The key is to attach a condition to the Checkbox, and then perform the update based on the condition.

First, open the UI designer for your Setup Project.

[image: Open UI Designer]

Then, add a new dialog to the UI flow.

[image: Add a dialog]

Select one of the Checkboxes dialogs.  Any one, [they are all the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1354920/).

[image: Select a checkbox dialog]

You then have a new dialog in your UI Flow.  Click on it.

[image: new dialog]

In the property sheet, specify the name for the checkbox "property".  This symbol will take the value 1 if the checkbox is checked, something other than 1 (I don't know) if unchecked.

[image: checkbox property]

Finally, attach to one of your other installer actions, a condition, using that property. 
For example, you can conditionally update a registry key or value, only if that checkbox has been checked. View the registry designer, then select a node:

[image: Registry designer]

Then in the property sheet, specify CONDITION=1, for the condition, where CONDITION is the name of the property you attached to the checkbox in the step prior.

[image: Specify the condition]